# Why does GCC produce ANDL $-16?

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit, disassembly, gnu-assembler

I need some help understanding why GCC is doing

```
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp   # ???
    subl    $48, %esp    # ???
    movl    $8, 16(%esp)        
    movl    $4, 20(%esp)
```

Why does it first subtract 16 and then subtract 48 again? Wouldn't it be easier to do `subl $64, %esp`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
andl    $-16, %esp   # ???
```

The above line is not subtracting 16 from `esp` but to *align* it to 16 byte boundary.
While the following one is to subtract, mostly for reserving some space on the stack.

```
subl    $48, %esp    # ???
```

Comment: It's `AND` not `ADD`, oh my god. Now I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Why would it align it to 16 bytes? It's 32bit, not 64, the abi does not mandate that, I think that you can avoid that by setting -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 (that would align the stack to 4 bytes unless a bigger alignment is needed)

Comment: @Marco "Why would it align it to 16 bytes?" That's because the default value of `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` is 4. Nothing to do with the architecture, also as you've pointed out, the ABI didn't specified about it. I think it's set for optimizations with SIMD instruction families.

Comment: what does this mean "align it to 16 byte boundary", I looked up mpreferred stack boundary and it looks like it's to set the frame size, but I don't think thats it since it then subl's 16

Comment: @SteveG `what does this mean "align it to 16 byte boundary"`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224564/what-does-alignment-to-16-byte-boundary-mean-in-x86 `since it then subl's 16`: I don't know what you mean by `subl's 16`